# How to get Users Email Id in Facebook application using PHP?

Tags: php, facebook

I have created a simple Facebook application in PHP, that greets user by there user name,
I also want there Email id, to be displayed. But i am not able to do that. the code that i am using is,

```
require_once('facebook.php');
require_once('config.php');
$facebook = new Facebook(APIKEY, SECRETKEY);
$user=$facebook->require_login();

echo $user; // displaying the ID
<div style="padding: 10px;" id="greeting">
   <fb:if-is-app-user uid="loggedinuser">
      <h2>Hi <fb:name firstnameonly="true" uid="loggedinuser" useyou="false"/>! welcome to facebook</h2>
  <fb:else>
       <h2>Hi <fb:name firstnameonly="true" uid="loggedinuser" useyou="false"/>! welcome to facebook</h2>
   </fb:else>
   </fb:if-user-has-added-app>
</div>
```

the Output that i am getting is,

```
1000002020202020
Hi User! welcome to facebook
```

I want the Email address to be displayed along with the user name, i searched many code but did not get any solution. and if you any good facebook tutorial site please post the links too..

Comment: I think Facebook API does not allow to retrieve user's real email ids, you can get only their proxy email ids

Comment: @Mithun P Facebook API allows you to receive real email id, but it depends upon the user, who will give permission to your application to do that. we can also access Albums Info, Date of birth and all profile information which is in the users profile...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the Email Address, directly without using the FQL.

```
// initialize facebook
 $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => APP_ID,
        'secret' => APP_SECRET));

 $session = $facebook->getSession();
 if ($session) {
 try {
    $fbme = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
  }
}
else
{
  echo "You are NOT Logged in";
}

//getting the login page if not signned in
if (!$fbme) {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('canvas' => 1,
                                      'fbconnect' => 0,
                                      'req_perms' =>                   'email,user_birthday,publish_stream',
                                      'next' => CANVAS_PAGE,
                                      'cancel_url' => CANVAS_PAGE ));
 echo '<fb:redirect url="' . $loginUrl . '" />';
 } else {

      // $fbme is valid i.e. user can access our app
     echo "You can use this App";
 }

 // getting the profile data
 $user_id = $fbme[id];
 $name=$fbme['name'];
 $first_name=$fbme['first_name'];
 $last_name=$fbme['last_name'];
 $facebook_url=$fbme['link'];
 $location=$fbme['location']['name'];
 $bio_info=$fbme['bio'];
 $work_array=$fbme['work'];
 $education_array=$fbme["education"];
 $email=$fbme['email'];
 $date_of_birth=$fbme['birthday'];
```

This code worked for me..and i go all the information needed with the Email ID.

```
NOTE: User has to allow us to get their Information during the Approval of Application.
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to ask for extended permissions when the user authorizes your application, so you can have access to the user email.

Here's an example using the new PHP SDK and the Graph API:

```
<?php

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/config.php');

// initialize facebook
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => APP_ID,
            'secret' => APP_SECRET));

$user = $facebook->getUser();
$session = $facebook->getSession();

// in case we don't have a valid session, we redirect asking for email extended permissions
if ($user == null || $session == null) {
  $params = array();
  $params["canvas"] = "1";
  $params["fbconnect"] = "0";
  $params["next"] = CANVAS_URL;
  $params["req_perms"] = "email";

  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);

  echo '<fb:redirect url="' . $loginUrl . '"/>';
  exit();
}

// get user email via the new graph api, using the fql.query method
$url = "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query";
$url .= "?access_token=" . $session['access_token'];
$url .= "&query=SELECT email FROM user WHERE uid={$user}";
$userData = simplexml_load_file($url);
$userEmail = $userData->user->email;

echo 'The user ID is: ' . $user;
echo 'The user name is: <fb:name uid="' . $user . '" />';
echo 'The user email is: ' . $userEmail;
```

Comment: the result i got by running the $url (in browser)..
<fql_query_response list="true">
−
<user>
<email>mymail@gmail.com</email>
</user>
</fql_query_response>

but $userData was getting null.. i dont know why this is happening?

Comment: maybe there's some issue with simplexml in your server, you could use $json = file_get_contents($url); instead, adding "&format=JSON" as a parameter in $url, and then $userData = json_decode($json, true);

Comment: ok, i will try that...but any way i am getting the Email id. Thank you @agbb

Comment: thank you. I've also spent hours to figure it out and I'm going to post my answer below.  Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the help. I finally figure out how to do that.

first, I need to get the access token, NOT the user session one, but the one for admin.

So, here is the code:

```
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token';
$ch = curl_init();
$params = array(
                'grant_type'=>'client_credentials',
                'client_id'=>$appId,
                'client_secret'=>$secret,
                );

$opts[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = http_build_query($params, null, '&');
// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$url");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$adminAccessToken = curl_exec($ch);
// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

And then, I can use the facebook API to get any user who accept the application and the extended permission like that:

```
$fql    =   "select name, hometown_location, sex, pic_square, email from user where uid=1000000001";
    $param  =   array(
       'method'     => 'fql.query',
        'query'     => $fql,
        'access_token' =>$adminAccessToken ,
      'callback'    => ''
    );

    $fqlResult2   =   $facebook->api($param);
```

with the access token, i can also post things onto user's wall. :)