# Facebook Login : How do I get the users email?

Tags: facebook

I'm new to the facebook api, but I have this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Facebook Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
  <script>
     FB.init({ 
        appId:'my_app_id', cookie:true, 
        status:true, xfbml:true 
     });
  </script>

  <fb:login-button perms="email">Login</fb:login-button>    

</body>
```

I would like to know, when a user accepts my perms or when they return to my site, how do I get that users email adderss?

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362885/how-to-get-users-email-id-in-facebook-application-using-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the javascript sdk documentation, they have a similar example of doing this. Try something like:

```
FB.api(
    {
      method: 'fql.query',
      query: 'SELECT email FROM user WHERE uid='+FB.getSession().uid
    },
    function(response) {
          alert('Email is ' +response[0].email);
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

this will help :

FB.api('/me', function(user) {
            if(user != null){
                document.write(user.email);
}
})

call this function after user gives you permission